# Why do I only get real-time tweets from Twitter's streaming API sample endpoint?

Tags: twitter, processing, twitter4j

As the sample that Twitter provides consists of 1% of all tweets. I expected it to give me random tweets from the past and present - but when I wrote a piece of code in Processing using Twitter4j, it just retrieves the real-time tweets.

Comment: I you want people to answer your question, put your question in the post, and show what you're doing, describing what you expect, what's going wrong, and why you think it's going wrong. Your current post does not contain enough information to do anything with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's incorrect, the public streams ["offer samples of the public data flowing through Twitter"](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public), so that is real-time data and not historical.

If you did want to retrieve historical Tweets with Twitter4J, you could use the [`Twitter#search(Query query)`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/SearchResource.html#search%28twitter4j.Query%29) method to do it.